# how to add a jpg image in Latex

Tags: latex

I want to insert a .jpg image(that is in my current folder, where the .tex file is) after a paragraph. How can I do it in Latex? What should I include / what commands should I use?

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You need to use a graphics library. Put this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

You can then add images like this:

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=90mm]{fixed_dome1.jpg}
\caption{A simple caption \label{overflow}}
\end{figure}
```

This is the basic template I use in my documents. The position and size should be tweaked for your needs. Refer to the guide below for more information on what parameters to use in `\figure` and `\includegraphics`. You can then refer to the image in your text using the label you gave in the figure:

```
And here we see figure \ref{overflow}.
```

Read this guide here for a more detailed instruction:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions

Comment: The image it's displayed OK, the caption also, but at the compile time i got the error '\caption outside float'

Comment: You don't really need to worry about these errors that much. You can also place the label inside the caption, like so: `\caption{caption \label{overflow}`

Comment: Could you be using `\caption` after `\end{figure}`, i.e. outside the float?

Comment: No, i'm using: 

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=100mm]{fig1.jpg}
\caption{My caption....}
\label{Fig.1}
\end{figure}

Comment: If you want the image to fit *half* the width of your *text block*, just write `\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{fixed_dome1.jpg}`. Instead of `\textwidth` you can use `\paperwidth` (width of the whole page) `\linewidth` (within the current line).

Answer (score 9):

if you add a jpg,png,pdf picture, you should use pdflatex to compile it.

Comment: It complies but it is giving the name of the file saved on its right side ..what to do?

Comment: the pdflatex part of this answer is what I upvoted - a usual latex command won't do the trick!